# Count unique items (colours) across multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQL table that stores colours in three columns; red, green and blue. The values range from 0 - 255 for each column. I have created a query that will tell me how many unique colour values there are (only about 200), but what I now want to do is to count how many rows of each colour value appear in my table.

The output I'd like is:

```
- red green blue count
- 000 000   000  12
- 255 000   000  56
- 000 255   000  45
- 255 255   255  97
```

And so on. I've tried about 10 different queries from all over the web and SO but none seem to do the job. Can anyone help?

Oh, and please note my table has over 200 million entries so something reasonably fast would be appreciated :)

Comment: You don't know how to count in SQL? Use `COUNT`. Or you don't know how to aggregate rows to groups? Use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: To clarify: I wrote above comment instead of an answer, because I think rather then copying a ready-made query you should get a tutorial or book and learn. This is a very basic query, so just trying "10 different queries from all over the web" without understanding them obviously is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a basic `group by` query:

```
select red, green, blue, count(*)
from t
group by red, green, blue;
```

Comment: Oops, sorry added comment to wrong poster - even though the query is the same, you did come in first :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add all 3 color fields to the select list and the group by clause and add a count(*) to the select list. This will tell you the counts for all combinations:

```
select red, green, blue, count(*)
from table
group by red, green, blue
```

You can add a composite index on red, green, blue columns to speed the query up.

Comment: Thanks so much - you rock! All done in 4:35s. Saved me a tonne of work!

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
select count(distinct col1),count(distinct col2) from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT red,green,blue, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM colorsTable 
GROUP BY red,greenmblue
```

As you can see GROUP BY` gets the job done